# Can't verify password on client side

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, web, pdf.js

I am trying to use `pdf.js` on my webpage where I need to verify that the password entered by the user of PDF is correct before uploading it to the server.

But I am not able to make it work.

I used CDN hosted `pdf.min.js`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.min.js" integrity="sha512-Z8CqofpIcnJN80feS2uccz+pXWgZzeKxDsDNMD/dJ6997/LSRY+W4NmEt9acwR+Gt9OHN0kkI1CTianCwoqcjQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and this is the password checking function:

```
function checkPass() {
pdfjsLib.getDocument({
        url: 'pdf.pdf',
        password: '01010101'
    }).promise.then(function (pdf) {
        input.classList.add("rightpass");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        input.classList.add("wrongpass");
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

and in the console log, it logs `Deprecated API usage: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified.`

I tried to disable it by `pdfjsLib.disableWorker = true;` but it didn't work.

I just need to verify the password and nothing else no rendering.

Comment: what is the purpose of this? if you verify the password at the client, you achieve no security because your back end endpoint is till open for uploading unverified files and your password check can be circumvented. the correct way to filter out unwanted pdf files is at the server - upload any file, test the password, delete the file and return an error if passwords don't match.

Comment: The client side password checking of pdf files is for faster ui experince.

Comment: so you are double-checking the password at the back end?

Comment: not really. the pdf is password protected and to do the work of processing with less common error such as wrong passwords i check them on client side.

Comment: i c. well, i could not find any good documentation on pdf.js (which is surprising, given who's the vendor). sorry, i cannot help you any further. i suspect, though, that the "depreciated" warning is not related to the fact that you are unable to verify the password.

Comment: I don't what's going on behind the scene. I added the cdn script of worker and it worked but popping warning of `Setting up fake server` which is not an error after hours of seeing online answers. I too didn't found any good documentation of it that's why i asked it here.

Comment: i have some recollection that several years ago there was a need of client side pdf form filling and after an extensive research i didn't find anything good - didn't like the open-source pdf.js because of the many issues and the lack of documentation and tried to contact several proprietary vendors, who turned out to be extremely greedy and hard to negotiate with, and with no obvious benefits (they also had problems and showed no intent to fix them). eventually we ended up using pdf.js anyway. i'll try to find some code and see if it could help here.

Comment: you've got a working sample!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code sample:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.6.347/pdf.worker.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const pdfName = "empty-protected.pdf";
    async function loaded()
    {
        const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ url: pdfName, password: "qwerty" });
        loadingTask.promise.then(() => console.log(1, "OK"), (ex) => console.log(1, ex));
        
        const loadingTask2 = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ url: pdfName, password: "" });
        loadingTask2.promise.then(() => console.log(2, "OK"), (ex) => console.log(2, ex));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:loaded();">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the password-protected pdf file (password is `qwerty`) that I used for the experiment:

https://mega.nz/file/lJg2GKgS#AdVJ0DZ1OfsGrlSqM67dfr_r2n8lBiiOm9q0o4wt7e4

Incliding `pdf.worker.min.js` changes the warning `"Warning: Deprecated API usage: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified."` to `"Warning: Setting up fake worker."`

Comment: as i mentioned in my comment that pdf.worker.min.js was the one which i needed. as this is the core layer of the library. see here https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/ thank you daniel for your time buddy.